# which of the following are finite dimensional?

Tags: vector-spaces

[image]

My Attempt:

I)  Since  $P_3=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ are basis of $P_3$ and dimension of $P_3=4$  finite dimensional

II) Dimension of $R^5$ is 5 hence finite dimension

but i don't  about other options

Comment: What is the notation $F(-\infty,\infty)$?

Comment: It'd be nice to know **over what field** are those supposed spaces defined...perhaps all of them are assumed to be real space?

Comment: The fifth option is clearly all constant functions, which has obviously dimension $1$.

Comment: @DHMO.. i don't the what is the notation of $F(\infty,\infty)$

Comment: @DonAntonio I assume over $\Bbb R$ with pointwise addition and multiplication

Comment: @DonAntonio...vector spaces over the field  $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @rajendra That $\;F(-\infty,\,\infty)\;$ thing is really bewildering, but not as much as you not knowing what it means. You should *at least* know what the question you post is talking about. Your teacher **must** know, or the book you use must have that notation.,

Comment: @DonAntonio...I preparing for an exam i got this question

Comment: @rajendra what book did you get it from?

Comment: @DHMO...what is the dimension of C[a,b]

Comment: @rajendra I believe $C[a,b]$ is infinitely dimensional, since you can form a basis by partitioning that interval, and you can partition that interval into as many pieces as you want.

Answer (score 1):

III. $P_n\subset C[a,b]$ for all $n$ so there exist   as large as you want linearly independent systems of vectors  $\Rightarrow C[a,b]$ is not finite dimensional

IV. I don't know what  is denoted by $F(-\infty, \infty)$.

V. This is the space of constant functions, i.e. the space $P_0$ that has $dim=1$

Upd. The dimension of the space $C[a,b]$ is uncountable because no infinite-dimensional Hilbert space can have a countable basis.
For this example it can be seen directly by proving the linear independence of the system of functions $\{x^\lambda\mid 0\leq\lambda\in \mathbb R \}$.